# What method can I override to trigger events when a subclass of JButton is enabled/disabled

Tags: java, swing, inheritance, triggers, jbutton

I've created a sub-class of JButton. I was able to override mouse events with the following code:

```
@Override
protected void processMouseEvent(MouseEvent e) {
    super.processMouseEvent(e);
    // My event code...
}
```

I was wondering what I should override to get events to happen when the object is enabled or diasbled.

My subclassing of JButton was mostly for cosmetic reasons, just so I can set exactly what the buttons look like. I want to be able to gray out the buttons when they become disabled. If you think I should be doing this a different way, please let me know.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need to override anything. Enabling or disabling the button will trigger a propertyChange event with "enabled" as the property name.

Comment: So I would implement a PropertyChangeListener? Is that correct?

Answer (score 2):

override enable(), disable(), and setEnabled() ?

btw, overriding processMouseEvent() sounds... dirtyish... you should probably add a MouseListener instead

Comment: Yeah... MouseListener appears to be the way to go. I think I was getting a little crazy there...